# How to exclude body from swagger for GET method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, jersey-2.0

I was using swagger with Jersey on top of Spring-boot. My API looks like the following:

```
@Component
@Api
@Path("/")
@Produces("application/json")
public class MyApi {
    @GET
    @Path("/items/{id}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get item by id")
    public Item getItem(
            @ApiParam(value = "the item id", required = true)
            @PathParam("id") String id) throws Exception {
        // ...
    }
}
```

When I browser to the Swagger UI, I found that there is a body parameter under this method. How can I get rid of it? There should not be a body parameter for the GET method. I cannot try this method from the Swagger UI as a result of this.

I was using swagger-jersey2-jaxrs 1.5.0

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try the latest version - 1.5.13?

Comment: Thank you Helen. 1.5.13 fixed the problem.